# Write a jQuery script that detects a button click and makes an AJax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, netbeans

What I am trying to write a jQuery script that detects a button click and makes an Ajax call to a json-data-students.php `PHP` script on my server using the .getJSON() function.

I am using Netbeans IDE 8.0.2 I have successfully connected to Mamp and have uploaded my database. I have copied my html and php files to my htdocs folder in Mamp and it still won't call the function which is to display student data. Here is my code, any help as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. I'm pulling my hair out over here!!!

This is the html doc button on my page with the script call at the top of the page.

```
<div data-role="content">             
</div>
<div id="studentList">
<button id="studentButton">Get Student Info</button>
```

This then is the js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8888/php/json-data-students.php',
function(data) {
//Loop through data and extract infromstion for outer listview and       inner list view (Part 6 & 7)
$.each(data.students, function(index, student) {
$("#studentList").append('<li><a href="#page2">'+ student.firstName +' '+ student.lastName +'</a><ul><li>Student ID: '+student.studentID+'</li>\n\
                                                                                                                          <li>Course ID: '+student.courseID+'</li>\n\
                                                                                                            <li>Module ID: '+student.moduleNo2+'</li></ul></li>');
});
//Rebuild the list to ensure styling is applied 
            $("#studentList").listview("refresh");
        }); //End of JSON Call
    }); //End of document ready function
```

Error message in Netbeans:

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (11:59:47:660 |   error, network)
     at http://localhost:8888/php/json-data-students.php

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (11:59:48:567 | error,    network)
 at http://localhost:8383/favicon.ico
```

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (11:59:48:578 | error,  network)

```
 at ot.each.contents (chrome-    extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/jquery.min.js:2:51 70)
    at ot.extend.map (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/jquery.min.js:1:14862)
     at ot.each.ot.fn.(anonymous function) (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/jquery.min.js:2:5271)
     at (anonymous function) (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/components/ActivityMonitor/vie      ws/overlay/ActivityMonitorOverlayView.js:1:1894)
  at ot.extend.each (chrome-   extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/jquery.min.js:1:14059)
    at ot.fn.ot.each (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/jquery.min.js:1:11922)
   at n.Class.create.bindActivityDetectors (chrome-  extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/components/ActivityMonitor/views/overlay/ActivityMonitorOverlayView.js:1:1853)
at i.Class.create.init (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/components/ActivityMonitor/ActivityMonitorController.js:1:255)
at API.Settings.init.n.ready.API.Component.load.onLoaded (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/content.js:1:979)
at (anonymous function) (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/ComponentFactory.js:1:943)
at q.execCb (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:12206)
at b.check (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:6455)
at (anonymous function) (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:8720)
at (anonymous function) (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:710)
at (anonymous function) (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:9104)
at each (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:236)
at b.emit (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:9072)
at b.check (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:7000)
at (anonymous function) (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:8720)
at (anonymous function) (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:710)
at (anonymous function) (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:9104)
at each (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:236)
at b.emit (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:9072)
at b.check (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:7000)
at b.enable (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:8970)
at b.init (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:5560)
at (anonymous function) (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:7499)
at (anonymous function) (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:710)
at (anonymous function) (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:9104)
at each (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:236)
at b.emit (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:9072)
at b.check (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:7000)
at b.enable (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:8970)
at b.init (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:5560)
at (anonymous function) (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:7729)
at (anonymous function) (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/cajon.js:1:710)
at n.finishLoad (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/text.js:1:1576)
at (anonymous function) (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/text.js:1:1797)
at     define.node.d.env.d.env.undefined.process.versions.process.versions.node.xhr.d.env.d.env.n.createXhr.n.get.a.onreadystatechange (chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/core/vendor/text.js:1:2866)
```

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (11:59:50:461 | error, network)

`

Comment: what error are u getting in console ?

Comment: Your function is called once when the document loads. There is nothing attached to the `click `event on your button so nothing will happen when you click it.

Comment: The whole file has worked on someone elses mac when I sent it to them? My click event calls the json file and appends the list no?

Comment: Hi Jad I have added the error message appearing in netbeans up above in an edited version as it wsa too big to comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are sure the file path`http://localhost:8888/php/json-data-students.php` is correct I mean the port `8888` is it really running, Try one thing open your browser and enter the above url ad hit enter if get your json then url is correct else please check port of on which php is running

Comment: You hero that was the problem I had changed the mamp server some how!!! Thank you so much for your help Iv'e been trying to fix this problem for the last few days! Thank you!